# Git - all my new features disappeared from the project

Tags: git, heroku, github, commit

I wanted to push the new features which I made into the new the new branche. When I was done, I created the new branch, added new files (`git add .`), committed it (`commit -am 'new data'`) and pushed it to Heroku (`git push heroku master`, `git push heroku new_branch:master`).

I am not sure if I didn't ran the `git init` command.
Now when I open the project, there are all "olds" data, there aren't involved the new features which I made.

Is there any way to restore them?

Thank you so much, I was working on those features for a few days, so hope I didn't lose them...

**EDIT:**

The output of `git branch -a`:

```
  master
* new_design
  remotes/heroku/HEAD -> heroku/master
  remotes/heroku/master
  remotes/heroku/new_design
```

**EDIT2:**
The output of `git checkout master`:

```
Checking out files: 100% (10688/10688), done.
M   config/database.yml
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is behind 'heroku/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
```

**EDIT3:**
Here are the critic commits from log:

```
commit 60574e2a80917721e2cf0806e5d1eedc3c2adc06
Author: me
Date:   Wed Jan 2 15:33:51 2013 +0100

    new design

commit 58e846e372464eb32d29535abf1edce88ca0e5a9
Merge: b5f503b 8f2e5da
Author: me
Date:   Wed Jan 2 15:05:46 2013 +0100

    WIP on master: b5f503b Design updated to get the rest of the site

commit 8f2e5da65df5b22419baa45fb6a7b81fcbc7a20b
Author: me
Date:   Wed Jan 2 15:05:46 2013 +0100

    index on master: b5f503b Design updated to get the rest of the si
```

Comment: I doubt anything is lost by a push. You should have all your files locally at least.. Where did you make these changes? Master or in your new branch? What's the output of git branch -a ? You shouldn't be using git init except you want to create a new local project and pull an existing project from a remote repository into it. Tho a better option is to use git clone to receive a remote repo to work on it locally..

Comment: If you didn't do git init, all the other git commands won't work

Comment: Did you develop the features inside the new_design branch or did you create it after creating features without applying the stash correctly? In this case do a git checkout master and check if your changes are maybe there..

Comment: I added into the project some files (images, PDFs) - these files I can see in the project locally. But when I take a look at the source code, there is displayed the time of change on 3:05PM - in all files where I build new features.

Comment: gulty - I built all new features, then created the `new_design` branch, put the data there. When I run `git checkout master` -> check out please the OP.

Comment: And none of the features are in your master? You can use git log to see all your commits. Then you can use git diff commit1 commit2 to compare 2 commits.. Like that you can find your last working version with all your features. If you've done that you can use git checkout commitx to get that back.. And afterwards you can just go on as normal..

Comment: It sounds like you added a bunch of files in a single commit to `new_branch`, and then never merged it into `master`. Based on what you've described in your question, you *shouldn't* be seeing your new files on your `master` branch.

Comment: Ok, so in the log I found the commit with time since what are all my source files changed. But when I run `git diff commit_a..commit_b > my.patch`, I got just an empty file :/

Comment: @meagar, so I should just run `git checkout master`, then `git merge new_design` and then should be it fixed?

Comment: Depends. You said that you added new files. But you also said that you developed new features before which I guess are not inside those files(pdf's etc..) but inside some other files of the master.. If I were you I would recreate the moment with all your code written by finding the correct commit and checking it out. And re-add the images and files afterwards again.. If your new features are currently NOT in the master then a checkout and a merge won't do anything but putting the PDF's inside the master branch but your code will still be missing..

Comment: Guys, please, take a look on the OP - I added the output from log with some information. There are also some `merge` keys/codes. The source files where I put the new features are all updated in `15:05`, so it looks like those commits remove my features I made...

Answer (score 0):

did you try and see what you pushed to the server?

try cloning the repo to another location and see what you get.

also, is this a *"dumb http sever"*?

if so, remember to call `git update-server-info` on the server side after every push.